Navisworks SDK - Export NWD
im trying to export a selection set to a new NWD file using the SDK, everything i try i hat a brick wall. Do you know if this is possible and if so does anyone have any pointers?
Tom.

Navisworks allows you to hide elements but not delete them directly. A practical workaround is to hide all elements except those in your selection set, then save the model as a new NWD file. When reopened, only the elements in the selection set will be visible, while hidden elements remain in the model.
The Navisworks API typically mirrors the functionality of the user interface, so if a feature isn’t supported in the UI, it’s likely unavailable in the API as well.
https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-remove-element-in-Navisworks.html
